# Will I eventually be able to teleport assets between parachains?

Tags: xcm, teleport

The [Polkadot Wiki states](https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/learn-teleport#troubleshooting) that

> If you do not see "Accounts > Teleport" in PolkadotJS Apps, the source chain that you have selected does not support teleportation yet. As of June 2021, unsupported chains include Polkadot mainnet, Rococo testnet, and their respective parachains.

Looking at Kusama, I also only see two parachains in the PolkadotJS Apps dropdown menu to teleport KSM to, and from those two parachains I can only teleport to Kusama.

Will I eventually be able to teleport between parachains, or is it always relay chain <-> parachain?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are two questions in here, one related to trust between chains and the other related to the message transport protocol.

First, the use of teleportation has to do with how much two chains trust each other, and not the message path (Relay <-> para vs. para <-> para). You will be able to teleport between parachains, as long as they have a trusted relationship. For chains that don't have a trusted relationship, they use reserve backed asset transfers. For a high level difference, check out [Gav's article](https://medium.com/polkadot-network/xcm-the-cross-consensus-message-format-3b77b1373392) on XCM. To get more in the weeds, the [XCM v2 spec](https://github.com/paritytech/xcm-format/tree/v2#initiateteleport) has more formal definitions.

Second, all messages currently go through the Relay Chain using XCMP-lite (aka HRMP). Once XCMP is fully implemented, channels will indeed be directly between parachains, and they would use teleportation or reserve backed transfer depending on their trust relationship.

Finally, regarding Polkadot vs. Kusama, XCM has currently mostly been used on Kusama (with the exception of upgrade messages from the Relay Chain to Shell/Statemint). We expect this functionality to come to Polkadot in one of the next releases.

Comment: Could you expand on what it means for two chains to trust each other? And: does every teleportation and reserve backed asset transfer path (channel?) need to be implemented or activated separately by both participating chains? There is no way to do this one-sided?

Comment: "Trust" would be up to the governance of each chain. For common good parachains at least, it means "under the same governance system". For example, the `Root` origin on Statemint is equal to the `Root` origin on the Relay Chain, so they trust each other. Other parachains (e.g. Moonbeam) have their own governance system and definition of `Root` origin, so the Relay Chain doesn't _trust_ Moonbeam as a teleporter because Moonbeam's governance could choose to mint themselves more DOT, while Statemint's could not (because Statemint's == the Relay Chain's).

Comment: Channels do need to be opened, so one chain requests a channel with another, which must accept. These channels are configured for any type of message, not just reserve backed transfers and teleports.