# I want to enable Teleport Asset functionality in XCM between two parachains. How should I do it? Also, how do I teleport asset from Para1 to Para2?

Tags: polkadot, xcm, xcmp, orml-xtokens, teleport

My aim is to teleport an asset on parachain1 to parachain2. But I saw in parachain code, that teleport is disable. How do I enable it? I am confused about Teleport in XCM.

Basically, how do I make it work?

what is the path of teleport; (para->relay->para) or (para<->para)?

Does HRMP Channel opened between parachains works for teleport or something else should
be done? How does HRMP channel affect teleportation of asset?

Does teleport works using Xtoken?

Please guide me through teleportation of asset between two parachains using XCM.

Answer (score 4):

First check this old answer in StackExchange to see the difference between [Asset Teleportation and via Reserve Asset Transfers](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/37/how-can-i-transfer-assets-using-xcm).

You will be able to teleport between parachains, as long as they have
a trusted relationship.
If we take a look at [Kusama runtime](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/master/runtime/kusama/src/xcm_config.rs#L352) in the config of xcm_executor we see this line.

```
type IsTeleporter = TrustedTeleporters;
```

Where it specifices the parachains that have a trusted relationship (Statemine and Encointer):

```
    parameter_types! {
      pub const Ksm: MultiAssetFilter = Wild(AllOf { fun: WildFungible, id: Concrete(TokenLocation::get()) });
      pub const Statemine: MultiLocation = Parachain(1000).into_location();
      pub const Encointer: MultiLocation = Parachain(1001).into_location();
      pub const KsmForStatemine: (MultiAssetFilter, MultiLocation) = (Ksm::get(), Statemine::get());
      pub const KsmForEncointer: (MultiAssetFilter, MultiLocation) = (Ksm::get(), Encointer::get());
      pub const MaxAssetsIntoHolding: u32 = 64;
  }
  pub type TrustedTeleporters =
    (xcm_builder::Case<KsmForStatemine>, xcm_builder::Case<KsmForEncointer>);
```

About the channels currently you need them. [Check this old response in StackExchange](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/1386/2762).

> All messages currently go through the Relay Chain using XCMP-lite (aka HRMP). Once XCMP is fully implemented, channels will indeed be directly between parachains, and they would use teleportation or reserve backed transfer depending on their trust relationship.

To teleport the asset, I recommend you to first check the tutorial [Transfer assets with XCM](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/connect-relay-and-parachains/transfer-assets-with-xcm/) to know how to set up the environment, is using [Zombinet](https://docs.substrate.io/test/simulate-parachains/) to set up a local test network to simulate a relay chain with validators and parachain collator nodes.

When you have it all running you have to execute the extrinsic `limitedTeleportAsset` from the pallet `xcmPallet`.
In this extrinsic you have to specify the destination parachain, the beneficiary account (Account ID of the account you are teleporting the asset), the asset that is going to be teleported, the feeAssetItem and the weightLimit for the XCM fee purchase.

For a more detail guide check this workshop on Youtube [Parity Technologies: XCM Workshop | Polkadot Decoded 2022](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UfxU3hUprKo) where it performs an asset teleportation and a reserve assettTransfer.

Comment: I have implemented this thing but in the second parachain, I got an event of untrusted teleport location. So, how should the untrusted teleport location be resolved?

Comment: Do you have this line type IsTeleporter = TrustedTeleporters; where you define your parachain as one of the trusted teleports?

Comment: yes, I have this line

Comment: with your Parachain defined there too? pub const Statemine: MultiLocation = Parachain(1000).into_location();

Comment: yes, I`ve defined it. It is showing UNTRUSTED TELEPORT LOCATION

Comment: Can we achieve teleport by including SPREE mechanism ? I understand that RelayChain cant just trust X parachain but what if the x parachain has its runtime'not changed and the record it's in relay chain. Am sure by that it can be trusted right? @Alex Bean

Answer (score 2):

By default, Para-chains don't trust each other.But there are two ways that u can teleport the assets.

First, You need a sovereign account of your parachain in the relay chain and you need to use `Transfer asset` instruction in the  `fn send message` .

Secondly, You can even send the assets through the fn `teleport-assets`, but parachains only trust the assets from sovereign account. You need to change the ensure [here](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/master/xcm/xcm-executor/src/lib.rs#L492).