# XcmError "UntrustedReservedLocation" & "TooExpensive" while transfer assets between two parachains (limitedReservedTransferAssets)

Tags: parachain, xcm, assets, xcmp

I'm trying to integrate stablecoin into parachain.
First of all, I tried to repeat the steps shown in the video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UfxU3hUprKo&t=1182s) with standard settings:

Running with zombienet:

Relay chain - Westend

Para1 - Westmint

Para2 - Westmint

Firstly, create assets for each parachain and make xUSD sufficient:

[image]

I do similar steps, but at the `limitedReservedTransferAssets` stage I get an error on the side of the receiving parachain - Para2. Error `XcmError::TooExpensive`, although everything is similar with the example and in `xcm_config.rs` everything is also standard. This is a fairly standard transaction that cannot exceed the allowed weight.
The first question is how can this be fixed?

The second question is this.
I do similar steps on this video, I just connected a custom parachain and at the same stage the transaction falls with the `XcmError::UntrustedReserveLocation` error, which is also not very clear. Where to look in this case?

My steps to produce error:

[image]

[image]

After submitting the transaction:

Got this on Para1:

[image]

And this on Para 2:

[image]

Thank you all in advance

Answer (score 1):

The instructions are probably correct, but there is probably something wrong with your Configuration of the XCM executor.
Like other components in Substrate and FRAME-based chains, the XCM executor is modular and configurable, and has to be properlty configured in order to make the XCM instructions between chains work.

If you want to go more in deep in the configuration I suggest you watch this video: [XCM Config & Pallet-XCM | Polkadot Deep Dives](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bFMvWmU1pYI).

The `XcmError::TooExpensive` is triggered with the `BuyExecution` instruction, when the fees declared to purchase weight are insufficient. So you probably need to have funds on the asset you are paying fees or modify the Config to accept other assets.

And the `XcmError::UntrustedReserveLocation` means that the origin register doesn't contain a valid value for a reserve transfer notification. So probably here you can take a look in the previous StackExchange question suggested by @wakar-seraj-khan [I want to enable Teleport Asset functionality in XCM between two parachains. How should I do it? Also, how do I teleport asset from Para1 to Para2?](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/6776/i-want-to-enable-teleport-asset-functionality-in-xcm-between-two-parachains-how/8990#8990).

In case you want to test with the same setup of the video you are watching, you need the same binaries he is using (notice the version is an old one, as the video):

Clone & build Polkadot

```
git clone -b release-v0.9.30 --depth 1 https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot
cd polkadot && cargo build –-release
```

Clone & build Cumulus

```
git clone -b polkadot-v0.9.30 --depth 1 https://github.com/paritytech/cumulus
cd cumulus && cargo build –-release
```

Clone & build [Trappist](https://github.com/paritytech/trappist)

```
git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/paritytech/trappist
cd trappist && cargo build --release
```

You can take a look in the XCM configuration Trappist has implemented [here](https://github.com/paritytech/trappist/blob/main/runtime/trappist/src/xcm_config.rs).

Answer (score 0):

The issue of UntrustedReserveLocation happened because parachain don't trust each other. [Here](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/8990/3136) is the solutions for the UntrustedTrustedLocation which is similar to UntrustedReserveLocation. You can teleport the assets from one chain to another.

Comment: Ohh, thanks for you answer. But, what exactly do you mean I have to change in my code?
I have this parameter types for my chain
` parameter_types! {
...
      pub const Statemine: MultiLocation = Parachain(1000).into_location();
      pub const KsmForStatemine: (MultiAssetFilter, MultiLocation) = (Ksm::get(), Statemine::get());
...
  }
  pub type TrustedTeleporters =
    (xcm_builder::Case<KsmForStatemine>, xcm_builder::Case<KsmForEncointer>);`

And I use this variable. So what can be a problem?